# How to display data in an object

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, ajax

When outputting data, they are displayed in one line. How to make sure that every record is an object and all objects turn into an array?

```
<?php
  require_once("db.php");
  $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM  `dictdb`.`dictwords`');
  while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "
           id: " . $row['id'] . ",
           engWord: " . $row['engwords'] . ",
           rusWord: " . $row['ruswords'] ."
          ";
  }
?>
```

test.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn-test").on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/src/php/tests.php",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
              $(".test-word").html(data);
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're inserting plain text into HTML. That's meant to be with `<tags>` ignoring your whitespace (like line breaks).

**Either load some reasonable HTML from PHP**

```php
## in PHP
...
echo "<p>
  id: " . $row['id'] . ",<br>
  engWord: " . $row['engwords'] . ",<br>
  rusWord: " . $row['ruswords'] ."<br>
</p>";
...
```

**Or, better, work with JSON**

```php
## in PHP
...
$results = [];
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  $results[] = $row;

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($results);
...
```

```js
## in JS
$.ajax('/src/php/tests.php')
.done(data => { // use .success for older jQuery versions
  let formatedJSON = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
  $(".test-word").html(`<pre>${formatedJSON}</pre>`);
});
```

Comment: How do I access a specific object? $ (". test-word"). html (formatedJSON [2]); does not work. thanks

Comment: @Aleksf, `formatedJSON` is already a string here. For specific property of an object, use the original object and the property's key, like `data.id`, `data.engWord` etc... Example: `$(".test-word").html(data.engWord)` or `$(".test-word").html("English: " + data.engWord + ", Russian: " + data.rusWord);`

Answer (score 0):

Put the desired HTML tags in the data you echo.

```
echo "<br>
       id: " . $row['id'] . ",<br>
       engWord: " . $row['engwords'] . ",<br>
       rusWord: " . $row['ruswords'] ."<br>
      ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `echo` does not produce a JSON object. You would need to do something like:

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");
  
$query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM  `dictdb`.`dictwords`');

$response = [];

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $response[] = [
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'engWord' => $row['engwords'],
        'rusWord' => $row['ruswords'],
    ];
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

This would produce a JSON object similar to (if you had 2 results returned from DB):

```
[
    {
        id: 'YourID',
        engWord: 'Your Eng Word',
        rusWord: 'Your Rus Word',
    }, {
        id: 'YourID',
        engWord: 'Your Eng Word',
        rusWord: 'Your Rus Word',
    }, 
]
```

Rather than try to parse HTML, i'd highly recommend using a JSON response.

Answer (score -1):

When you use the function query you are asking for a query execution on your database. So, to see what returns in case of reading queries, you should check the doc of that function, but i'm pretty sure it's an object because when you do $query->fetch, you are using a method of that object.

Instead, for what concerns the array, just try to use a try-catch (my bad for repeating) handling exception block and see, if it gives you an error when converting to array, then it means you can't convert those data into an array.